# Azure App Service running Linux with Node 18, responded with a MIME type of "text/plain" on React UI

Tags: reactjs, linux, azure, web, azure-web-app-service

I have a basic react application, built with Vite. The build runs fine, dev server run fine, preview runs fine. However, deploying to Azure App Service /home/site/wwwroot and then access the UI running on a Linux App service, i am getting the following error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I have tried adding a web.config file at the base of the UI (/home/site/wwwroot) i have also tried adding it /home/site. Yet i cannot get around this issue. Seem its happening on a `.mjs` file thats running in the browser. Screenshot attached for reference.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Linux App Service doesn't like `.mjs` files by default and ignores when you try to add the MIME type to a web.config (maybe there is another way to add it, I don't know).

I resolved this by changing my vite bundler to output the JavaScript files as .js rather than .mjs and this worked.